# Interfacing CMUSphinx with PyAIML - Input/Output Streams

Tags: java, python, python-2.7

I have a simple chatbot written in Python using PyAIML and I am running a Java Speech-to-Text system running alongside it.
Now, I want to pipe the output from Java into Python.

Here is what I've tried so far :

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\path\\to\\chat_bot\\");

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python chat.py", null, file);
OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Stdout: " + line);
}

String input = in.nextLine();
input += "\n";
writer.write(input);
writer.flush();
```

Now, I have AIML installed in Python 2.7 but for some reason, the default has been set to Python 3.3
Also, the error I get from Java is :

`java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed`

I have changed the Windows Registry to set Python 2.7 as default, but that was of no use.
So, how can I set Java to run the python in the `C:\Python27` folder? 
I really don't wanna uninstall Python 3.3 just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (instead of Runtime.exec). Besides that, you should probably use the full path to the version of python (e.g. use `c:\\Python27\\bin\\python` instead of just `python`) that you want.

Comment: I tried ProcessBuilder as well. Both gave same errors.
The suggestion to use the full path worked, I think.
But I think I need to multithread the input and output streams because right now, I get no response from Python.
What do you think?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: The Input and Output streams, do they need to be in separate threads?

Comment: Are you multiplexing? Runtime.exec is starting another process. And if you need to read and write simultaneously then you'll need separate reading and writing threads. Normally you read and then write.